# Fetch fake COCKTAIL API

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have small project with cocktails, I want to use forEach function to separate object and it show me error , can you tell me what I am doing wrong ? Thanks

```
const url = 'https://thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=d'
const output = document.querySelector('.cocktailbody')
 
const drinks = fetch(url)
 .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
     console.log(data)
     
    data.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log(item)
      })
    
  })


CONSOLE MESSAGE: web.js:11 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.forEach is not a function
    at web.js:11
```

Comment: What is the response you are receiving from your network request? The error indicates that it may not be what you are expecting.

Comment: console.log(data) works

Comment: {drinks: Array(25)}

Comment: So the value for drinks is an array, but the value of data is an object.

Comment: Then you want `data.drinks.forEach(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access **object** with the `forEach()` method which is used for **Array**.

Use `data.drinks.forEach(function(item){})` instead of `data.forEach(function(item){})`.

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const url = 'https://thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=d'
const output = document.querySelector('.cocktailbody')

const drinks = fetch(url)
 .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
     console.log(data)

        data.drinks.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log(item)
      })

  })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
Hi There
</body>
</html>
```